# Nuxt 3 ContentQuery component data types not recognized by WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, nuxt3

I am trying to make use of the `ContentQuery` built-in component like so:

```html
<ContentQuery
    path="/posts"
  >
    <template #default="{ data }">
      <pre></pre>
      <ul class="post-list">
        <li v-for="post in data" :key="post._path" class="post-list__item">
          <PostListItem :post-data="post" />
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
    <template #not-found>
      <p>No posts found.</p>
    </template>
  </ContentQuery>
```

The code and logic works, the problem I am specifically facing is that in my `PostListItem` component the `post-data` has an `any` type, thus when accessing the properties of post data WebStorm gets fussy. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

I took a look into [awesome starter](https://github.com/viandwi24/nuxt3-awesome-starter/blob/v2/pages/post/index.vue)

And with a bit of more decrypting I came up with this:

// PostListItem.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from "vue";
import type { ParsedContent } from "@nuxt/content/dist/runtime/types";

defineProps<{ postData: ParsedContent }>();
</script>
```

I am using TypeScript 4.8.4 (bundled), maybe this is may be the reason why I have to explicitly import defineProps, otherwise this did the trick, I am now getting full postData auto-completion, the ParsedContent import does seem a bit strange.

EDIT:

I did notice however that If I have custom front-matter, that of course doesn't get typed so I did this to extend them:

```js
interface PostDataTypes extends ParsedContent {
  date?: string;
}
```